# Recursion TypeError

Tags: python

```
from functools import lru_cache 

@lru_cache(maxsize = 1000)   
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        
for n in range (1, 101):
    print(fib(n)/ fib(n-1))
```

Just started learning python, looking at recursion.
Say I have this code here. Why would this cause a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'. Meanwhile changing the range print to this works. Either way I should be computing the fib, so why would it cause a type error? I know it has to do with the n-1, just wanted a little more explanation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 32, in 
print(fib(n)/ fib(n-1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

```
for n in range (1, 101):
    print(fib(n+1)/ fib(n))
```

Comment: The stack trace will tell you where, and to a more experienced eye likely why, the error is happening. Always post your stack trace. And show which input caused it. For example, what happens when you input zero (`n - 1` when `n` is 1 on the first iteration)?

Comment: `I know it has to do with the n-1` well, when n=1, n-1 is 0 and your method doesn't handle 0, so it returns None instead of an integer value

Comment: Oh, I am stupid, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration `fib(n-1)` is going to be `fib(0)`. Since your function does not tell Python what to return if `n < 1`, Python makes it return `None`. Then the program tries to divide the valid output from `fib(n)` by `None`, which does not work and gives you the error you are encountering.

To fix the issue, you can start the `range` from 2 or you can change the if condition slightly:

from `if n == 1:`
to `if n <= 1:`

Comment: Yeah, i dont know how i missed that. I've been studying all day and I think i need to take a break hahaha.

Comment: Technically, the first two numbers you define should be `fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = 1` and not `fib(1) = 1, fib(2) = 1`